# Como utilizar hover em minhas imagens para aparecer um texto acima dela

Tags: css, html5

Este é o código completo da pág. em html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Galeria de Fotos</title>
<link href="estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="corpo">
  <div id="banner"></div>
  <div id="menup">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Início</a></li>
      <li><a href="contexto.html">Contexto</a></li>
      <li><a href="personagens.html">Personagens</a></li>
      <li><a href="narrador.html">Narrador</a></li>
      <li><a href="enredo.html">enredo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
   <br>
  <br>
  
  <div id="conteudo">
     <div class="fotos"><img src="basilio.jpg" /></div>
     <div class="fotos"><img src="luisa.jpg" /></div> 
     <div class="fotos"><img src="jorge.jpg" /></div>
     <div class="fotos"><img src="juliana.jpg" /></div>
     <div class="fotos"><img src="leopoldina.jpg" /></div>
     <div class="fotos"><img src="dona felicidade.jpg" /></div>
     <div class="texto"> luisa trai jorge</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="rodape">
    <p>Criado pelos alunos do 2ºB ETIM Informática</p>
    <p>ETEC Ferraz de Vasconcelos | 2016 &copy;</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>


</html>
```

E este é o código CSS

```css
.fotos{  
  height:300px;
  width:400px;
  background-size:100% auto;
}

.texto{
  padding:20px;
  font-family:Arial;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  opacity:0;
  transition: opacity .2s linear;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}
 
 .imagem:hover .texto{
  opacity:1;
 }
```

O que quero é basicamente passar o mouse em cima da foto e aparecer um texto em cima da foto, no caso, um para cada foto, de cada personagem.

Comment: foi mal... esqueci o codigo... ja vou colocar o codigo completo

Comment: Sugiro que refaça a pergunta de forma correta, o código que postou abaixo como resposta, na verdade faz parte da pergunta certo ?

Comment: certo!!! desculpe, é q sou nova aqui..

Comment: @Renan Carlos, me ajuda, se der claro.. preciso resolver logo isso sabe.. grata desde já!

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque além de muito antiga, não parece haver grande interesse por parte do usuário que elaborou a pergunta, e apresenta níveis baixos de interesse.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui vai um exemplo **básico:**

```css
#Container{
 width:90%;
 height:auto;
 padding:10px;
 background:#d3d3d3;
 position:relative;
}
#foto{
 width:200px;
 height:100px;
 fonte-size:16px;
 background:#abcdef;
 position: relative;
 top: 5px;
 left:50px;
 line-height:100px;
}
#comentario {
 position:relative; top:-80px;
 left:170px;
 padding:2px;
 line-height:20px;
 background:#333;
 color:#fff;
 display: block;
 width:120px;
 opacity: 0;

 -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
 -moz-transition: all 300ms ease;
 -ms-transition: all 300ms ease;
 -o-transition: all 300ms ease;
 transition: all 300ms ease;
}

#foto:hover  #comentario{
      opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="Container">
 <div id="foto"><img src="basilio.jpg"/> Aqui vai a foto do Basilio
         <div id="comentario">E aqui o comentário sobre o Basilio</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Acredito que o código está auto explicativo. Quando se passa o mouse por cima da `DIV` com o `id="foto"` exibe o comentário.  **IMPORTANTE:** A `DIV` Comentário deve estar dentro da `DIV` onde irá  passar o mouse!

Comment: Muito grata!!! Ajudou muito . vou testar.. agradeço!

Comment: @BrendaChicarelli Espero ter ajudado, caso tenha mais duvidas. Altere a pergunta com o que está precisando.